# How to know if the other user is now writing a message in web chat website?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, chat

I am building a chat system in an ASP.Net MVC website, and I want the user see if the other chat user is now writing a message.

The same as it appear in gtalk or msn, when the other user start writing it says: "userA is writing ...." then it hide this message when the user stops.

What will be the concept behind this feature to implement on a website, and what I should know to build it the right way?

Comment: The concept is that for every *n* key presses, you send a ajax request to the server, which inturn pushes that out to all of the other clients.  Similar to how a site such as Google does auto completion as you type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all done via AJAX

User1 sends a `writing=true` value to the server as soon as writing begins, and `writing=false` when message is submitted.

User2 polls the server every `x` seconds to see `if(writing){display "User1 is writing a message"}`

This is obviously two way, so User1 and User2 are both pushing and pulling the `writing` boolean from the server.

I'd suggest using jQuery and JSON for this process.

Answer (score 0):

Look for an "on change" (or equivalent) for your edit text. Start a timer when it happens and send an ajax message to the chat server(s) to notify them. When the text is submitted or the timer runs out, clear the message.

Comment: It will need to be on key press or a variant, because on change is usually only fired when the input loses focus.

Answer (score 0):

Client-side, have a timer count to 500ms and a variable sentState set to false.

Whenever the client types something, reset that timer, the, if sentState is, send an AJAX request to the server indicating that the client is typing. Finally, set sentState to true.

If the timer reaches 500ms, send an AJAX request to the server indicating that the client is no longer typing and set sentState to false.